# MySql query to aggregate number of visitors present by hour of the day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate

I have a MySql table with visitor data showing when a visitor arrived and left and I'm trying to aggregate the data by time of day so that I can visualise the number of visitors:

```
+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|visitor   |entry_time                 |exit_time                  |
+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|a         |2017-11-20 11:30:00        |2017-11-20 14:15           |
|b         |2017-11-20 10:30:00        |2017-11-20 11:20:00        |
|c         |2017-11-20 09:50:00        |2017-11-20 17:05:00        |
|d         |2017-11-20 10:00:00        |2017-11-20 13:25:00        |
|e         |2017-11-20 12:40:00        |2017-11-20 16:30:00        |
|f         |2017-11-20 13:20:00        |2017-11-20 15:20:00        |
+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

I'd like to get the number of visitors present for each hour:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+
|time_of_day            |number_of_visitors |
+-----------------------+-------------------+
|2017-11-20 08:00       |0                  |
|2017-11-20 09:00       |1                  |
|2017-11-20 10:00       |3                  |
|2017-11-20 11:00       |4                  |
|2017-11-20 12:00       |4                  |
|2017-11-20 13:00       |5                  |
|2017-11-20 14:00       |4                  |
|2017-11-20 15:00       |3                  |
|2017-11-20 16:00       |2                  |
|2017-11-20 17:00       |1                  |
+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

I can create a query which counts the number of exits or entries by hour:

```
SELECT
    str_to_date(date_format((`entry_time`),'%y-%M-%D %H:00:00'), '%Y-%M-%D %H:00:00') AS `time_of_day`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `visitors`) AS `number_of_visitors`
FROM
    `tbl_visitors`  
GROUP BY 1
```

but I haven't been able to create a query that aggregates the total number of visitors present at any time of the day (and for any day of the week).

Comment: Change the group by

Comment: Create a calendar table. RIGHT JOIN with that table.

Comment: One aspect of this (null results) is a display issue, best handled in application code.

Comment: @jarlh Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calendar table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_calendar_hours(
  hour_of_day datetime PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Insert all the necessary dates with hours to this table

```
INSERT tbl_calendar_hours(hour_of_day)VALUES
('2017-01-01 00:00'),
...
('2017-11-20 08:00'),
('2017-11-20 09:00'),
('2017-11-20 10:00'),
('2017-11-20 11:00'),
('2017-11-20 12:00'),
('2017-11-20 13:00'),
('2017-11-20 14:00'),
('2017-11-20 15:00'),
('2017-11-20 16:00'),
('2017-11-20 17:00'),
...
('2017-12-31 23:00');
```

And use it in your query

```
SELECT
    h.hour_of_day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitor) AS number_of_visitors
FROM tbl_calendar_hours h
LEFT JOIN tbl_visitors v ON v.entry_time>=h.hour_of_day AND v.entry_time<DATE_ADD(h.hour_of_day,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
WHERE h.hour_of_day BETWEEN '2017-11-20 08:00' AND '2017-11-20 12:00' -- report for period
GROUP BY h.hour_of_day
ORDER BY h.hour_of_day
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c54427/12

Comment: The join should be ```ON v.exit_time > h.hour_of_day AND v.entry_time < DATE_ADD(h.hour_of_day, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)``` but otherwise this solution delivers